# Vertical scrolling in an iframe

Tags: html, powerbi-desktop

I have a report in an iframe built vertically and displayed on a TV.

But it's much bigger than the TV and I would like to add a way to auto vertically scroll the iframe through the html so that it scrolls without any interference and people can follow all the visuals in my report that are in the iframe.

Is it possible to apply the automatic vertical scrolling of the report that is in the iframe?

I tried to use this code but it didn't work:

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  
  </style>
  
  <script language="JavaScript1.2">
  
  var currentpos=0,curpos1=0,curpos2=-1
   function initialize()
   {
   startit()
   }
   
   function scrollwindow()
   {
   if (document.all) 
   temp=document.body.scrolltop
   else
   
   temp=window.pageYOffset
   if (alt==0)
   alt=1
   else
   alt=0
   if (alt==0)
   curpos1=temp
   else
   curpos2=temp
   if (curpos1!=curpos2)
   {
   if (document.all)
   currentpos=document.body.scrolltop+1
   else
   currentpos=window.pageYOffset+1
   window.scroll(0,currentpos)
   }
   else
   {
   currentpos=0
   window.scroll(0,currentpos)
   }
   }
   function startit()
   {
   setInterval("scrollwindow()",10)
   }
   window.onload=initialize
   </script>
   
   <body>
   <div id="contain">
   
   <!-- Aqui é onde vamos informar o código Iframe do relatório que você deseja inserir o auto scroll -->
   
   <iframe width="100%" height="1060" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNDJlYzA2ZjAtNzY1Yy00NjEzLWFiMTEtYzYwMmUwOWEyODkyIiwidCI6ImU2YmVkMTFkLWM2YzMtNDFkMC05NzU3LTkxNWQwZjIzZmQ4NyJ9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
   
   </div>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   
   </body>
   
   </html>
```

It should open by automatically scrolling the page down, and restarting.

But it did not work